# Viewport camera movement applies to all scenes - Any way to disable it?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm kind of new and I'm not sure if this is normal behavior or I clicked something accidentally, but moving around with my camera in the viewport changes the viewing angle of all of my scenes. Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: Hello :). Yes this is normal behavior. You can work around it by assigning a different camera to each viewport.

Comment: Are you talking about an actual "Camera" object used for rendering, or the "abstract" camera used to display the 3D viewport ? Because I don't think there is a way to differentiate between scenes that way. You can however use a different workspace for each scene and circle between them when you change scenes. But this doesn't feel like a good workflow.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't talking about an actual camera object, just the figurative "camera" that you use to look around the viewport. Just wanted to know if this was normal, it's not causing much trouble just seemed odd to me.